# Unable to publish DB project on Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

With `Visual Studio 2019` (already updated to the latest version), I have created a new `SQL Server Database Project` connected to an `Azure SQL Datawarehouse Database`.

I imported all the object already present on the database `(tables, stored procedure and schema)`, I carried out the schema compare which does not detect any difference.

On the project properties I changed the Target platform setting it up on `Miscrosoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse`, I switched the Compatibility level setting it on `SQL Server 2017 (140)`

The build of solution is successful, but when I tried to publish the solution I have the following message error

```
Creating publish preview...
    Errors occurred while modeling the target database. Deployment can not continue.
```

I can generate the publish script only if I check the box `Always re-create database`, but I don't want drop and re-create the database every time

I did a lot of research but none of them solved my problem.

Anyone knows if there are any known limitations concerning the publish of `SQL Server Database Project` on `Azure SQL Datawarehouse Database` or does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Having membership in the db_owner role of the target database has resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying database projects to Azure SQL Data Warehouse is in public preview since August if you use Visual Studio 2019 SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-install-visual-studio). At the bottom of the page Microsoft gives you instructions on how you can provide feedback directly to the SSDT team.

Database projects were not supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse as you can read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7666dff3-5db2-4b5a-a568-9ec0538a0a4d/import-azure-sql-data-warehouse-as-a-database-project-in-visual-studio) and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/13313247--in-preview-database-project-from-visual-studio-t).

Comment: Can you try compatibility level of 130?

Answer (score 0):

Check your database tables in the "System Tables." If you have `dbo.sysdiagrams`,
that won't allow you to deploy the db.

So, if you delete `dbo.sysdiagrams` table on your database, that will hopefully allow you to deploy the database.

They get created when you click on the database diagrams.

[image]